# How can i clear this error? I'm at the finish line and need to fix my input overloader

Tags: c++

Here is the error code I am getting:

```
/tmp/cczLRrEI.o: In function main:
main.cpp:(.text+0x95): undefined reference to operator>>(std::istream&, rational const&)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x15b): undefined reference to operator>>(std::istream&, rational const&)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x340): undefined reference to operator>>(std::istream&, rational const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here is my `operator>>` overload function:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& input, rational& fraction) {
    int numerator, denominator;
    char slash;
    input >> numerator >> slash >> denominator;
    fraction = rational(numerator,denominator);
    return input;
}
```

I believe this is where the issue is at!

My main function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "rational.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char oper;
    string operators = "+-*/?<>";

    rational result;
    rational operand;

    cout << "Enter op1 (in the format of p/q): ";
    cin >> result;

    // Test rational class member function
    do {
        cout << "\nEnter operator [+, -, /, *, =, ?(==), <(less), >(greater), c(lear), a(ccessors), q(uit)]: ";
        // TODO: Read the operator into oper
        cin >> oper;
        // TODO: Change the pseodocode below to test oper for binary operators
        bool check_oper = false;
        for (char const& x : operators) //range based for loop to check the string 
        {
            if (oper == x) 
            {
                check_oper = true;
            }
        }
        if (check_oper) 
        {
            cout << "\nEnter op2 (in the format of p/q): ";
            cin >> operand;
        }

        // ToDo: Implement a switch or multiway if statement with one case for
        // each option above where
        // '+','*','/','-' inputs a rational op1 and calculates
        // result.oper(result,op1)
        // '=' outputs the current result,
        // 'c' to clear current result, use input function to read first
        // operand into result, 'a' to test accessors, 'q' to quit.
        switch (oper) 
        {
        case '+':
            result = result + operand;
            // result += operand;
            break;
        case '-':
            result = result - operand;
            break;
        case '*':
            result = result * operand;
            break;
        case '/':
            result = result / operand;
            break;
        case '=':
            //outputs current result
            cout << "result = " << result;
            break;
        case '?':
            // ternary operator
            // condition ? return if true : return if false
            cout << ((result == operand) ? "Correct! Good job!" : "Oh no! Good Try!") << endl;
            break;
        case '<':
            cout << ((result < operand) ? "True, great!" : "False, try again!") << endl;
            break;
        case '>':
            cout << ((result > operand) ? "True, great!" : "False, try again!") << endl;
            break;
        case 'c':
            cout << "\nEnter op1 (in the format of p/q): ";
            cin >> result;
            break;
        case 'a':
            cout << "result's numerator is: " << result.getNumerator() << endl;
            cout << "result's denominator is: " << result.getDenominator() << endl;
            break;
        }
        if (cin.fail()) 
        {
            cin.clear(); cin.ignore();
        }
    } while (oper != 'q');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @David `char const& x` to `char const &x`, and `int main()` to `int main ()`, along with all your other intra-line spacing and brace formatting changes, are stylistic choices that do not belong in an edit of someone else's post. Please refrain in future.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I won't quibble with your the spacing, I just let GNU indent clean it up. No more stylistic than  your clean up. The purpose is to make the code in the question readable.

Comment: My clean up was _solely_ for Markdown so the whole block is formatted. That's not stylistic _at all_. We don't modify other people's coding styles. It was perfectly readable without moving ampersands and adding spacing in function calls (and, in my personal opinion, it's far more readable in the OP's style! Though that's not the point) Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You didn't show all your code, but we can see the problem.

Somewhere, you declared:

```
istream& operator>>(std::istream&, rational const&)
```

That's what's being used.

Except it can't be, because your definition is:

```
istream& operator>>(std::istream&, rational&)
```

You lost the `const`, so it's a separate function. The one you're using wasn't defined.

Pay close attention to the details of the types in your code, and of the type(s) mentioned in your errors.